# Best way to set the working expiration of android application

Tags: android, security

I am developing one android application.
Now I want user to restrict the user with the working of the application.
Way is,
As soon as user install the application I will ask for the activation code. The activation code can be purchased from the application website.
Now the application can work for next 6 month. 
As soon as the 6 month gets over the user will be again asked for new activation code.

Now my problem is how to restrict this.
User can change the time of the mobile device. So I can' restrict this.

I don't want to use webservice for this licensing process.

what can be the best process to avoid this kind of problem.
thanks In advance.
Bskania.

Comment: You can either (1) rely on the device time (which you correctly stated can be changed), or (2) use a web service.  There is no third way.  The web service doesn't have to be your own. You can use any NTP server to retrieve current time and use it.  Naturally, you'll need a working internet connection for this purpose.

Comment: Or you can implement a sort of timer that counts while the application is installed, put it in a `Service` so it runs in the background... but yeah, it can be disabled.

Comment: you don't want to use webservices, but you don't want to rely on the time of the device ? If your device has GPS, Location.getTime() may give you the GPS time (still changeable with mockGPS or such, though)

Comment: Typically, activation codes go with a validation server to avoid the same code to be used on different devices and to be able to dynamically change the validity date.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I will go with device time only. Assuming that it is correct and set as automatic network time.

Comment: I had solved it like this. Every time the application will be open i will first check the date between the license date. If it will proper then  I will check for the date of last open application with current date, if it is after that then the date is not changed and if its before then I will show the dialog as your license is expired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had solved it like this. Every time the application will be open I will first check the date between the license date. If it will proper then I will check for the date of last open application with current date, if it is after the last opened date then the date is not changed and if its before then I will show the dialog as your license is expired.